# "On web `bytes` is required" exception thrown by image_picker plugin on Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-image, appwrite, flutter-image-picker

My app is using the `image_picker` plugin to let the user upload a profile picture from his phone and on Android everything works as expected.

The problem is that when I try to run the same code on web, it throws me the following error:

```
Error: AppwriteException: null, On web `bytes` is required (0)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
    at new input_file.InputFile.new (http://localhost:42231/packages/appwrite/src/input_file.dart.lib.js:79:17)
    at database.DatabaseService.new.uploadProfilePic (http://localhost:42231/packages/presents/services/database.dart.lib.js:299:104)
    at uploadProfilePic.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at database.DatabaseService.new.uploadProfilePic (http://localhost:42231/packages/presents/services/database.dart.lib.js:297:20)
    at http://localhost:42231/packages/presents/screens/profile/show_profilepic_menu.dart.lib.js:262:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:40641:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:40511:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:35438:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:35999:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:36037:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:35872:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:35906:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:42231/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

I don't know if the problem is with the `image_picker` plugin or with AppWrite (the backend server), but since when I run the code in Debug mode it stops in the `image_picker_for_web.dart` file I'd guess the problem is with the former.

Actually, it stops on line 274 where it returns an `XFile` without the `bytes` parameter (see the code below), so maybe this is the problem? **How can I fix that?**

(the code of `image_picker_for_web.dart` I was talking about, from line 273)

```
if (!_completer.isCompleted && files != null) {
        _completer.complete(files.map((html.File file) {
          return XFile(
            html.Url.createObjectUrl(file),
            name: file.name,
            length: file.size,
            lastModified: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
              file.lastModified ?? DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
            ),
            mimeType: file.type,
          );
        }).toList());
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after some further debugging I found out the problem was not with the `image_picker` package but with uploading the picked image on AppWrite storage.

Initially, I was uploading it with a code like this one:

```
Future<void> uploadProfilePic(XFlie file) async {
  File res = await _storage.createFile(
    bucketId: Constants.profilePicsBucketID,
    fileId: 'unique()',
    file: InputFile(
      path: file.path,
      filename: '$_uid.${file.path.split('.').last}',
    ),
    read: ['role:all'],
  );
}
```

And then I solved my problem passing the `createFile` function also a `bytes` parameter. So my final code is:

```
Future<void> uploadProfilePic(XFlie file) async {
  List<int> fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();

  File res = await _storage.createFile(
    bucketId: Constants.profilePicsBucketID,
    fileId: 'unique()',
    file: InputFile(
      path: file.path,
      bytes: fileBytes,
      filename: '$_uid.${file.path.split('.').last}',
    ),
    read: ['role:all'],
  );
}
```